# Scala SBT to compile DSL into Scala or Java code

Tags: scala, sbt, dsl

There are two cases I have where some DSL specific code needs
to be compiled into Scala and/or Java code. Is there a ready
reference example that demonstrates

- how to specify dependency relation
- executing a relevant command to compile the DSL

One case is that of an [ONCRPC IDL compiler](https://github.com/dCache/oncrpc4j). A ".x"
IDL specification file is compiled into Java. Another case
is of compiling a [state map DSL (SMC)](https://github.com/dCache/oncrpc4j) code into Scala.

While learning Scala and Functional programming, and at
the same time applying to SBT seems steep, and need help.

Comment: I would search for a sbt plugin, or write one if I can't find. Take a look at a similar plugin for protobuf: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-protobuf it basically compiles your `.proto` files under `src/main/proto` to java files, and puts it under `src_managed` directory.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it should help me build the needed understanding. Following only a rant: In general SBT is so much powerful when compared with the others - it's so much more programmable. Yet at the same time the minimum needed skill to use SBT in such a context is so high, it makes me begin to wonder if this is the reason why the JavaScript based frameworks became so much popular - quick to start and build smaller solution. I have no doubt of Scala's (and that of FP) power.

Comment: I'll admit there's a learning curve, but I think it is well worth the effort. There's an excellent book on SBT by Josh Suereth. I'd recommend starting from there.